# how to remove the first element in list

Tags: list, prolog

I need to remove the first element from a list (the head). How do I do it?

Answer (score 7):

Maybe something like:

```
removehead([_|Tail], Tail).
```

Test:

```
prolog> removehead([1,2,3,4], R).
[2,3,4]
```

`R` is unbound here, and is used for binding it the result.

Comment: @moti: I would be surprised, if it wouldn't. Didn't test it though. You're welcome. :-]